# Arduino program running out of resources

Tags: c, function, http, arduino, wifi

I reset the wifi shields firmware, following [this](http://www.dfrobot.com/community/how-to-upgrade-arduino-wifi-shield-firmware-on-windows.html) tutorial.
Could that cause any errors later, if not done correct?

#### Edit2

I have still no idea where the problem could be. So i put my `.ino file` [here](http://oly-dorf.bplaced.net/Sensor.ino). (it's compiled: 25.052 Bytes)

I would be very pleased if someone could check if it's running on another environment, and report about it.
I replaced the sensor by fake values, so you don't need to add any hardware. Just need to add your router ssid and the password on top of the sketch.

If you comment the SD card part out you will see that it's running for some more time. But in general it doesn't change. It's behaviour looks like running out of any resource, like Udo Klein mentioned SRAM.

Just to check if i understood correctly:

- less code causes more free flash memory. But that should not affect the running program in SRAM isn't it? --> But why then different behaviour if some code parts (like SD card) are commented out?
- if i save lots of variables it lowers the amount of free SRAM. (Then it shoud be visible by MemoryFree.h lib --> which is telling me const ~6kB free)
- every time i 'return' from a function it will reduce the neccessary stack memory size, and local defined function variables call it's desctuctor by itslef?

Are there values saved in heap memory which is growing with every loop but lose reference at the end of a function call?

#### Edit

just run the same code like yesterday and it was working twice (-> it made continuously http requests and returned to the main loop() method as long as the program was running).
A restart did it!

so it looks like the reason is not only inside the code logic shown here. Any ideas where i could look for? Could there variables redefeined instead overwritting there value?

---

My C Code for Wifi shield on Arduino Mega 2560 should read out sensor data and make a HTTP request. Then print out both results to SD Card.

#### Problem:

The function responsible for network requests called from **[1]**, return ONLY after it's first call.

---

The setup method is initializing the serial connection and the sensor pins, further calling the following Wifi initialization method `initWifi()`to establish a network connection.

```
void initWifi(){
// check for the presence of the shield:
if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
  Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
  // don't continue:
  while(true);
}

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while(status != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network  
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  } 
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
}
```

The `loop()` method in general is looking like that:

```
...
File myFile = SD.open("sensor.txt", FILE_WRITE);      
if(myFile){    
  String timestamp = requestTimestamp();         <------ call from HERE [1]
  Serial.println("current date is: "+timestamp);

  myFile.println(String(cm)+"  "+timestamp);
  myFile.close();
  Serial.println(String(cm)+"  "+timestamp);
}
...
```

`requestTimestamp()` is the function which makes an HTTP HEAD request, and never return back into the loop() method (after it was working once perfectly!).

```
String requestTimestamp(){
  Serial.println("\nRequest timestamp");

  WiFiClient client;
  if(client.connect(server, 80)){
    client.println("HEAD / HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host:www.google.com");
    client.println("HTTP-date: asctime-date");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }  

  String time_str = "-1";
  boolean timestampKnown = false;
  while(client.connected() && !timestampKnown){
    String line = "";
    while(client.available()){    //  && !timestampKnown
      char c = client.read();

      if(c == '\n'){
        if(line.startsWith("Date:")){
          String DATE = line.substring(11, line.length()-4);
          time_str = formatTimestamp(DATE);
          Serial.println("-->"+time_str);
          timestampKnown = true;
        }

        Serial.println(line);
        line = "";
      }else{
        line += String(c);
        c = char();
      }
    }

    //if(timestampKnown)
      //break;
  }
  client.stop();

  Serial.println("--------------------------"+time_str);

  return time_str;   <--- from here it never returns to loop()
}
```

The `console output` looks like that:

```
SD card initialized.
Attempting to connect to SSID: ********
Connected to wifi

Request timestamp
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.de/?gws_rd=cr&ei=Gm5IUvXHEbeg4AON9YCwCw
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=9684aab183999fb2:FF=0:TM=1380478490:LM=1380478490:S=EnaD0yx20-9BT6-4; expires=Tue, 29-Sep-2015 18:14:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=R6OUfZAakXBBYSp_a9QRO56OzZxYS2X6RmpFlByzSOMgVXalyfYOuilvzQZjaNPRK9409kjjPsDIOEI4h44qIfljzYfS_57MrsQNaKp8S35iMUHKkgLwrkgGs7dRy6gQ; expires=Mon, 31-Mar-2014 18:14:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
-->20:14 29.9.2013
Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2013 18:14:50 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 258
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
Connection: close

--------------------------20:14 29.9.2013  <-- last line inside function before return
current date is: 20:14 29.9.2013  <-- printed from main loop() method
220  20:14 29.9.2013  <-- main loop() also




Request timestamp
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.de/?gws_rd=cr&ei=Im5IUvO5GvSs4AOyhYHoAw
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=f1a3f58848455aa8:FF=0:TM=1380478498:LM=1380478498:S=cwG8W2Ll10fiiu_e; expires=Tue, 29-Sep-2015 18:14:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=v_OGI8alGJj4TJEBZSjz9EYUJljTm58uBSxG_rdAcz6OIUNzoDLPGCBx_UlRw5jFkIKINivce2UhisHnEpsWJlFyQVLSG7n9Jkoopo-g2gNi0BgFbVXjXypcvA5SYBX9; expires=Mon, 31-Mar-2014 18:14:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
-->20:14 29.9.2013
Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2013 18:14:58 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 258
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
Connection: close 

<--- HERE: print out of the results like before is missing, and nothing futher happens......
```

Does the server care about how much of it's response i read out?
Could it be that the connection is still open, despite: HTTP 1.0, Connection: close and client.stop()?

The only reason i can imaging would be something related to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason might be that you are running out of RAM. You want to learn about [progmem](http://arduino.cc/de/Reference/PROGMEM). In addition you are working with String objects. I would try to avoid those. At least you should check [how much RAM you have actually left.](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but in this case it doesn't seem to be the point: `freeMemory()=6066` is const at the beginning of loop(). There's not much i am saving in SRAM.

Comment: if i put the freeMemory call inside the inner while(client.available()) loop, the last console output is: `freeMemory()=` without the number. Looks pretty arbitrary to me, isn't it???