# Is my Arduino 101 running out of memory?

Tags: python, c++, arduino

**EDIT: Updated with more minimal examples**

I'm implementing an artificial neural network on an Arduino 101, and  when instantiating a network with 8 input nodes, 7 hidden nodes and 4 output nodes (`small_network`) it runs OK and completes instantiation with ~10KB of memory left.

Likewise, when I attempt to do the same thing using a network with 20 input nodes, 10 hidden nodes and 1 output node, it completes instantiation with ~8KB of memory left.

However, when I attempt to do the same thing using a network with 20 input nodes, **20** hidden nodes and 1 output node, it simply stops partway through resizing vectors. This looks like I'm running out of memory, but the 101 has 24KB of SRAM, and storing that many floats should only take ~2KB ; checking the available memory with `freeMemory()` also confirms that there are still over 9KB free before the resizing of the vector that fails.

Here is the header file for the `Network` class (apologies for the inclusion of `using std::vector`; I will fix it, I promise):

```
#include <MemoryFree.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

#ifndef NETWORK_H
#define NETWORK_H

#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include "Arduino.h"

using std::vector;

class Network {
    private:
        const int numInputNodes;                    // AKA 'InputNodes' in the original code
        const int numHiddenNodes;                   // AKA 'HiddenNodes' in the original code
        const int numOutputNodes;                   // AKA 'OutputNodes' in the original code
        float learningRate;                         // AKA 'LearningRate' in the original code
        float momentum;                             // AKA 'Momentum' in the original code
        float initialWeightMax;                     // AKA 'InitialWeightMax' in the original code

        long trainingCycle;                         // AKA 'TrainingCycle' in the original code
        float randomFloat;                          // AKA 'Rando' in the original code
        float errorRate;                            // AKA 'Error' in the original code
        float accumulatedInput;                     // AKA 'Accum' in the original code

        vector<float> hiddenNodes;                  // AKA 'Hidden' in the original code
        vector<float> outputNodes;                  // AKA 'Output' in the original code
        vector<vector<float>> hiddenWeights;        // AKA 'HiddenWeights' in the original code
        vector<vector<float>> outputWeights;        // AKA 'OutputWeights' in the original code
        vector<float> hiddenNodesDeltas;            // AKA 'HiddenDelta' in the original code
        vector<float> outputNodesDeltas;            // AKA 'OutputDelta' in the original code
        vector<vector<float>> hiddenWeightsChanges; // AKA 'ChangeHiddenWeights' in the original code
        vector<vector<float>> outputWeightsChanges; // AKA 'ChangeOutputWeights' in the original code

        void initialiseHiddenWeights();
        void initialiseOutputWeights();
        void computeHiddenLayerActivations(vector<float> inputs);
        void computeOutputLayerActivations();
        void computeErrors(vector<float> targets);
        void backpropagateErrors();
        void updateHiddenWeights(vector<float> inputs);
        void updateOutputWeights();
        void setHiddenWeights(vector<vector<float>> hiddenWeights);
        void setOutputWeights(vector<vector<float>> outputWeights);

    public:
        Network(int numInputNodes,
                int numHiddenNodes,
                int numOutputNodes,
                float learningRate,
                float momentum,
                float initialWeightMax);
        float trainNetwork(vector<float> inputs,
                           vector<float> targets);
        vector<float> classify(vector<float> inputs);
        void loadWeights(vector<vector<float>> hiddenWeights,
                         vector<vector<float>> outputWeights);

        int getNumInputNodes() const;
        int getNumHiddenNodes() const;
        int getNumOutputNodes() const;
        float getLearningRate() const;
        float getMomentum() const;
        float getInitialWeightMax() const;
        long getTrainingCycle() const;
        float getRandomFloat() const;
        float getErrorRate() const;
        float getAccumulatedInput() const;
        const vector<float> getHiddenNodes() const;
        const vector<float> getOutputNodes() const;
        const vector<float> getHiddenNodesDeltas() const;
        const vector<float> getOutputNodesDeltas() const;
        const vector<vector<float>> getHiddenWeights() const;
        const vector<vector<float>> getOutputWeights() const;
        const vector<vector<float>> getHiddenWeightsChanges() const;
        const vector<vector<float>> getOutputWeightsChanges() const;
        void setLearningRate(float learningRate);
        void setMomentum(float momentum);
        void setInitialWeightMax(float initialWeightMax);
};

#endif
```

Here is the constructor code for the `Network` class (I've omitted the other function implementations):

```
Network::Network(int numInputNodes,
             int numHiddenNodes,
             int numOutputNodes,
             float learningRate,
             float momentum,
             float initialWeightMax):
             numInputNodes(numInputNodes),
             numHiddenNodes(numHiddenNodes),
             numOutputNodes(numOutputNodes),
             learningRate(learningRate),
             momentum(momentum),
             initialWeightMax(initialWeightMax) {

Serial.println(F("In constructor"));
Serial.print(F("Free memory: "));
Serial.println(freeMemory());


trainingCycle = 0;
randomFloat = 0.0f;
errorRate = 0.0f;
accumulatedInput = 0.0f;

Serial.println(F("Resizing vectors..."));
Serial.print(F("Free memory: "));
Serial.println(freeMemory());

hiddenNodes.resize(numHiddenNodes);
outputNodes.resize(numOutputNodes);

Serial.println(F("Nodes done, Resizing weights..."));
Serial.print(F("Free memory: "));
Serial.println(freeMemory());

hiddenWeights.resize(numInputNodes+1, vector<float>(numHiddenNodes));
outputWeights.resize(numHiddenNodes+1, vector<float>(numOutputNodes));

Serial.println(F("Weights done, Resizing deltas..."));    
Serial.print(F("Free memory: "));
Serial.println(freeMemory());

hiddenNodesDeltas.resize(numHiddenNodes);

Serial.println(F("hiddenNodesDeltas done, Resizing outputNodesDeltas..."));    
Serial.print(F("Free memory: "));
Serial.println(freeMemory());

outputNodesDeltas.resize(numOutputNodes);

Serial.println(F("Deltas done, Resizing changes..."));
Serial.print(F("Free memory: "));
Serial.println(freeMemory());

hiddenWeightsChanges.resize(numInputNodes+1, vector<float>(numHiddenNodes));
outputWeightsChanges.resize(numHiddenNodes+1, vector<float>(numOutputNodes));

Serial.println(F("finished resizing"));
Serial.print(F("Free memory: "));
Serial.println(freeMemory());

initialiseHiddenWeights();
initialiseOutputWeights();

Serial.println(F("Finished constructor"));
Serial.print(F("Free memory: "));
Serial.println(freeMemory());
}
```

And here is the code that calls it:

```
#include <ArduinoSTL.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

#include "network.hpp"

int numInputNodes = 20;
int numHiddenNodes = 10;
int numOutputNodes = 1;
float learningRate = 0.3;
float momentum = 0.9;
float initialWeightMax = 0.5;

Network *network;

void setup() {
  /* Initialise Serial communication */
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial) ;

  /* Wait for script to notify readiness */
  while (!Serial.available()) {
    Serial.println(F("Ready"));
  }

  delay(1000);

  Serial.print(F("Free memory before initialisation: "));
  Serial.println(freeMemory());

  /* Init network */
  network = new Network(numInputNodes,
                     numHiddenNodes,
                     numOutputNodes,
                     learningRate,
                     momentum,
                     initialWeightMax);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(F("Running..."));
  Serial.print(F("Free memory: "));
  Serial.println(freeMemory());
  delay(1000);
}
```

Here is the Python script that communicates with the Arduino over Serial:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial, time, sys

# Open a Serial connection to the Arduino:
print "Connecting..."
try:
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout=1)
except:
    print "Failed to connect on /dev/ttyACM0"
    sys.exit(2)

print "success"

msg = ""
while "Ready" not in msg:
    msg = arduino.readline()
    print msg

arduino.write('#')

while True:
    line = arduino.readline()
    print line
```

The network with 8/7/4 neurons gives the following output:

```
user@machine:~/project$ ./monitor.py 
Connecting...
success
Ready

Free memory before initialisation: 14196

In constructor

Free memory: 13252

Resizing vectors...

Free memory: 13252

Nodes done, Resizing weights...

Free memory: 13252

Weights done, Resizing deltas...

Free memory: 12076

hiddenNodesDeltas done, Resizing outputNodesDeltas...

Free memory: 12076

Deltas done, Resizing changes...

Free memory: 12076

finished resizing

Free memory: 10900

Finished constructor

Free memory: 10900

Running...

Free memory: 10968
```

The network with 20/10/1 neurons does the same, but finishes with 7976B of memory

The network with 20/20/1 neurons gives the following:

```
user@machine:~/project$ ./monitor.py 
Connecting...
success
Ready

Ready

Ready

Ready

Ready

Free memory before initialisation: 14196

In constructor

Free memory: 13252

Resizing vectors...

Free memory: 13252

Nodes done, Resizing weights...

Free memory: 13172

Weights done, Resizing deltas...

Free memory: 9140

hiddenNodesDeltas done, Resizing outputNodesDeltas...

Free memory: 9060

Deltas done, Resizing changes...

Free memory: 9060
```

I've seen the related questions, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081698/arduino-program-running-out-of-resources) seems similar, but isn't really properly answered, and all the others seem to be much more straightforwardly running out of memory.

So then, **is my Arduino 101 running out of memory, and if so, why does `memoryFree()` think there's still plenty left? If not, what is it doing?**

(This is my first StackOverflow question, so if I've missed anything out or made any mistakes please do let me know and I'll endeavour to correct it.

Comment: Memory fragmentation?

Comment: Really we would want a [MCVE] here; that's a lot of code/output

Comment: BTW, never put things like `using std::vector;` in a header. You force every consumer of the header to accept `std::vector` in their default namespace.

Comment: Noted; I'll try and produce a smaller version.